# Global variable value not reflecting in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function OAuth.getSessionInfo returns response still why does the loop goes infinite?

```
var resp = false;
OAuth.getSessionInfo(function(data) {
  resp = true;
})
do {
    console.log("waiting............")
} while (!resp);
```

PS: Please suggest good title for the question.. I am confused on what should be the title for question

Comment: What do you get if you run this `console.log( data.sessionActive );` ??

Comment: I suggest adding a couple of `console.log`s in the branches of the if and printing out the value of resp as well in the do-while loop, just to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I am getting true correctly when tried console.log( data.sessionActive );

Comment: @mahaDev Looks like @user3707125 has answered your question. I checked it myself and it seems that once the do-while loop starts running, it does not allow any other piece of code to run. Hence, `resp` is never updated and the loop never breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets remind what multi-threading and concurrency means:

- Multi-threading - doing multiple things simultaneously.
- Concurrency - switching fast between multiple things, thus emulating them being done simultaneously.

Javascript neither supports the first technique nor the second one. Instead it executes block of code till the end, and then executes next  block that was scheduled with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` or one that came from event handler (e.g. `onclick`, `onload`).

Now if you look at your code you can see that it can't be completed without inner function being completed, but that inner function won't be executed until the outer one completes. And that's why your application hangs. You can also try next code which demonstrates your issue:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    x = false; 
    console.log("won't be invoked");
}, 0);        
var x = true;
while(x) {         
    console.log('looping');
}
```

P.S. This javascript's specifics is also the reason why there is no `sleep` function available - it simply doesn't make any sense to stop the only code executor you have.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an infinite loop because your while loop keeps running because it doesn't have a point to stop at. The way you have it now it says do this while true. So it keeps running.

Comment: "*it says do this while true*" You mean: do this while (resp ===) *false*?

Comment: @Marcus No it says do this while(true) I probably should have been clearer. Since sessionInfo is waiting for a response to come back the while loop does not know what the new value of `resp` is when it gets to the while loop so right now when it starts running the loop it `!resp` which was set to false so it does the opposite while(true)

Comment: Ugh. You're right. Forgot that `resp = false` to begin with which negates the `!` and reads `while(true)`. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Once the loop is started, you haven't updated the value of `resp`. Try the following:

```
var resp = false;

do {
    OAuth.getSessionInfo(function(data) {
        if (data.sessionActive == true) {
            resp = true;
        } else {
            resp = false;
        }
    });
    console.log("waiting............")
} while (!resp);
```

Comment: this will trigger too many api calls via OAuth.getSessionInfo().. I want this api to trigger only once

Comment: And how should `resp` be updated then? By the snippet you shared, it is causing an infinite loop if the value is false. The snippet I shared will call the API until you get `data.sessionActive` to be true. I don't know for sure if that is the desired result..